# My display will suddenly freeze

Tags: xorg, display

Ubuntu has been doing this for years. Usually I would just give it time and it would catch back up with itself (5 minutes or so). Recently, that hasn't been working. Essentially it's as if the entire desktop display freezes in place (except the mouse). Blinking things stop blinking and stay static. Things I hover over become unresponsive to the mouse. Back when it would catch up with itself, I could click something with the mouse and it would happen after the freeze stopped. Now it doesn't unfreeze and I have to switch to tty1 and issue sudo poweroff to fix the problem. This is especially problematic when trying to deal with word documents and browsing the web.

Specs:
Ubuntu 14.04 X86_64
Inspiron 15R with i5 hyper-threaded processor
8 Gigs RAM

I use Firefox 34 and LibreOffice. Haven't installed any display drivers. Thought it was related to flash. Was mistaken. Switching displays and issuing sudo service lightdm restart seems to be my best option.

Comment: if you are using compiz, set its settings to default, it does solved my problem once.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something was wrong the whole time, and now some change has occurred to keep it from eventually "righting" itself.  Since your virtual terminals still work, the problem has to do with your desktop.  Are you using appropriate video drivers?  Which word processor and web browser apps do you use?  Which version of Ubuntu?  Also, do your hardware specs meet minimum requirements for your version of Ubuntu?.  After all that, consider what your desktop is doing, such as screen effects.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Just updated my system specs.

Answer (score 0):

Like I was saying, it shouldn't have been doing that in the first place.  Install the package linux-image-extra-(yourversionhere) -- it's got the i915 and radeon drivers, which you should need one of.  Ya, libreoffice and firefox use quite a few threads, not to mention a fair amount of graphics processing.  Now if your system can speak to the gpu in the right language AND let it do more of the work, your stuff should run a lot smoother.  I sure hope that's what the problem is.

Comment: That package is already installed.